Connection string for connecting to SQL Server using SqlClient in Blazor hybrid on .NET 8
I have a question. I need use a special user account on SQL Server. This account has a user id and password. When I connect using an app on .NET 4.8, I don't have a problem, but when I try to connect using an app on .NET 8 (Blazor hybrid), I have a problem with the connection.
This is my connection string:
"ConnectionStrings": "Server=ServerAddress;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=User;password=Password;"

What do I need to add to my connection string? Why it is different between .NET 4.8 and .NET 8?
Thank you
I try connect to a SQL Server database from a .NET 8 Blazor hybrid app. Solution for .NET 4.8 is ok, but it didn't work on .NET 8.

Any error message? Perhaps try adding Encrypt=False

Finale i found working solution. I added TrustServerCertificate=True; to connection string. It works on .Net8 (Blazor hybrid).
Example:"ConnectionStrings": "Server=ServerAddress;Database=DatabaseName;User Id=User;password=Password; TrustServerCertificate=True;"
But i don't have answer on the question: why it is work on .NET 4.8 whiteout
TrustServerCertificate=True;
